# Rejection method

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, algorithms, simulation

I need to simulate a distribution using the rejection method
$$p(x) = c\begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{1+x^2} ,& x \leq 0\\
1, & 0<x<2\\
e^{-x}, & x \geq 2\\
\end{cases} $$

---

CDF is:
$$ F\left(x\right)=c \begin{cases}\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan x,& x\leq0\\
\frac{\pi}{2}+x,& 0<x<2\\
\frac{\pi}{2}+2+e^{-2}-e^{-x},& x\geq2 \end{cases} $$

As a distribution, we take the Cauchy distribution
$$q\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\pi\left(1+x^2\right)},\quad  Q\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan{x}+\frac{1}{2} $$

It can be obtained by the method of inverse functions as
$$-cot({\pi}u), \quad u \sim {U}\left(0,1\right)$$

Finding
$$r\left(x\right) = 
\frac{p\left(x\right)}{q\left(x\right)}=c\begin{cases}
\pi,& x\leq 0\\
\pi(1+x^2),& 0<x<2\\
\pi(1+x^2)e^{-x},& x\geq2
\end{cases} $$
$$M=\max_\mathbb{R}\frac{p\left(x\right)}{q\left(x\right)}=
c \cdot \max{\left(\pi,\sup_{[0,2]}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\pi\left(1+x^2\right)}},\sup_{(2,+\infty)}\frac{e^{-x}}{\frac{1}{\pi\left(1+x^2\right)}}\right)}=5c\pi  $$

We do according to the rejection scheme:
$$u\sim U(0,1),\quad \eta \sim {Q} $$

If $r\left(\eta\right)\le Mu$, continue.

Else $\xi=\eta$.

---

After modeling in Python [(code)](https://pastebin.com/YM2aRfun), I got the [following results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L207t.png).

But there is a gap near 1 (I suppose because of using $-cot(\pi u))$.
How that can be fixed?

Comment: Can you zoom in on the ECDF and CDF in the range say -2 to 4?

Comment: Another suggestion for a sanity check is to plot the actual sampling distribution that you got before considering rejections.

Comment: @Ian Zoomed: [Image](https://i.imgur.com/HkYWUwx.png)

Comment: That looks like every sample between 0 and 2 is being rejected. Are you perchance using the same $u$ that was used to draw the samples to determine the rejections?

Comment: @Ian But which $u$ I should use?

Comment: A new one independent of the old one. Which appears to be what you're doing anyway.

Comment: Well I see one problem, which is that you incorporated the normalization constant $c$ into $M$ but not into $r$ in the code. You need to either include it in both or neither. (The option of "neither" works because $r/M$ does not depend on $c$.)

Comment: @Ian Thank you! I added normalization $c$ to $r(x)$ and the gap disappeared, now it looks better — [Image](https://i.imgur.com/dkIJjUs.png).
One more question. Can I compare the resulting density histogram with $q(x)$ or with the original $p(x)$?

Comment: The thing that you want it to match up with is $p(x)$.

Comment: @Ian If we compare it with $p(x)$, it turns out like [this](https://i.imgur.com/BIWnKyf.png). It looks plausible, right?

Comment: The right tail looks fatter than it really should be...but that might just be a sample size issue.

Comment: @Ian It looks like it's something else. A significant increase in the sample by 10-100 times did not improve the situation :(
Any other ideas? [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hfX4i8LQ)

Comment: I'm not sure, I threw together an implementation for this problem myself and I get pretty good agreement for 10000 samples.

Comment: @Ian Right, thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127072/discussion-between-artem-and-ian).